# как не записывать запятую в массив из файла с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дан файл input.txt

```
3 3
2, 4, 5
1, 0, 6
6, 3, 4
```

Я пытаю записать числа в двумерный массив, размер которого равен первой строчке файла (3х3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

/*3 3
2, 4, 5
1, 0, 6
6, 3, 4*/

int main() {

    std::ifstream inp("input.txt");
    std::ofstream outp("out_row.txt");
    std::ofstream otp("out_col.txt ");

    int max = 0;
    int min = 9;
    double mean = 0;
    int** a;

    int rows, cols;

    if (!inp.is_open()) {       // file isn't open
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
    }else{

        string ch;

        inp >> rows;
        inp >> cols;

        cout << rows << " " << cols << endl;

        a = new int* [rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            a[i] = new int[cols];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Строка
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) { //Столбец
                inp >> a[i][k];
                if (a[i][k] != ',') {
                    mean += a[i][k];
                    if (a[i][k] > max) max = a[i][k];
                    if (a[i][k] < min) min = a[i][k];
                    cout << a[i][k];
                }else {

                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }                     

        mean = mean / 9;

        outp << "Max = " << max << std::endl;
        outp << "Min = " << min << std::endl;
        outp << "Mean = " << mean << std::endl;

        inp.close();
        outp.close();
        otp.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            delete[] a[i];
        }
        delete[] a;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы точно знаете, что там ровно одна запятая - ну читайте ее в какой-то `char` - типа `char c; inp >> a[i][k] >> c;` - понятно, там, где она есть...

Comment: @Harry, но при переходе на следующую строку в c записывается первое число с новой строки

Comment: "понятно, там, где она есть..."  "*понятно, там, где она есть...*"  "**понятно, там, где она есть...**" "***понятно, там, где она есть...***" Еще раз повторить? После последнего числа в строке разве она есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Строка
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) { //Столбец
                    inp >> a[i][k];
                    //если в конце строки нет запятой, то и читать её не будем
                    if(k!=cols-1) inp >> ch;    //char ch - переменная для чтения запятой

               // if (a[i][k] != ',') {
                    mean += a[i][k];
                    if (a[i][k] > max) max = a[i][k];
                    if (a[i][k] < min) min = a[i][k];
                    cout << a[i][k];
              //  }else {

             //   }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```